# How to Realm setup in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing an error when including Realm API in to my Android project

Please provide instructions to set it up in Android studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you have included

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.0'
```

under dependencies in your build.gradle file